# In MongoDB 3.4.7 how to sort an arraylist / embedded documents without using unwind operator

Tags: aggregation-framework

I would like to sort arraylist element without using "$unwind" .

in the below example  "item" is array list, if I want to sort the data by item.category its not giving desired result. however if I flatten the structure using $unwind I am getting the desired results.

In my realtime data I have huge amount of data in the arraylist so if I use $unwind its hitting performance challenges that's why I am looking for sort without unwind, is there any ideas welcome !

```
db.ordersdup.insert([
     { "_id" : 2, "item" : [
     { "category" : "cookies", "type" : "chocolate chip" },
     { "category" : "cake", "type" : "lemon" },
     { "category" : "cake", "type" : "chiffon"},
     { "category" : "brownies", "type" : "blondie" }
     ],
     "amount" : 50 }
     ]);

Sample Query  
=====================
db.ordersdup.aggregate([  
   {  
      "$project":{  
         "_id":0,
         "Categories":"$item.category"
      }
   },
   //   {  
      $unwind:"$Categories"
   },
   {  
      $sort:{  
         "Categories":1
      }
   }
])

Results without $unwind 
==========================
{  
   "Categories":[  
      [  
         "cookies",
         "cake",
         "cake",
         "brownies"
      ]
   ]
}
My desired output would look like $unwind
{  
   "Categories":[  
      [  

         "brownies",
         "cake",
         "cake",
         "cookies"
      ]
   ]
}
Results with Flatten (i.e used $unwind)
========================================
/* 1 */{  
   "Categories":"brownies"
},
/* 2 */{  
   "Categories":"cake"
},
/* 3 */{  
   "Categories":"cake"
},
/* 4 */{  
   "Categories":"cookies"
}

Mongodb Database Version : 3.4.7 community edition, Environment Windows.

Thanks,
Nat
```